# Check All (multiple groups)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got multiple tables with the same class name.  I need each table to have a check-all/uncheck all check box inside each table and checks/unchecks all the other checkboxes within its own table.

I found other code on here that seemed like it would work; however, when attempting to plug it into my scenario, it didn't work at all.  I'm hoping to be able to use code that is close to being as clean as the code in my jquery example; however, if the code needs to change to another code to make it work, feel free to show me other code.  I am open to options, just want to make sure I am doing this the best way possible.  This is for a project; however, I'm hoping to learn how to do this so that I can continue using this in future projects.

I appreciate all the help I can get as I am pretty new to javascript/jquery.

Jquery

```
   $('#chkSelectAll').click(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('.permissions > input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
                $(this).prop("checked", true);
            });
        }
        else {
            $('.permissions input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
                $(this).prop("checked", false); $('#sel').text('Select All');
            });
        }
    });
```

html

```
<table id="table1" class="permissions">
<tr class="SLheader"><td><b>TABLE 1</b></td><td><input type="checkbox" id="chkSelectAll" /></td></tr>
<tr class="second"><td>First Row</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="first"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Second Row</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="second"></td></tr>
<tr class="second"><td>Third Row</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="third"></td></tr>
</table>

    <br />

    <table id="table1" class="permissions">
<tr class="SLheader"><td><b>TABLE 2</b></td><td><input type="checkbox" id="chkSelectAll" /></td></tr>
<tr class="second"><td>First Row</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="first"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Second Row</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="second"></td></tr>
<tr class="second"><td>Third Row</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="third"></td></tr>
</table>

    <br />

    <table id="table1" class="permissions">
<tr class="SLheader"><td><b>TABLE 3</b></td><td><input type="checkbox" id="chkSelectAll" /></td></tr>
<tr class="second"><td>First Row</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="first"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Second Row</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="second"></td></tr>
<tr class="second"><td>Third Row</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="third"></td></tr>
</table>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sfu7h8wf/

This jquery code does not work, at all.  I attempted to make sure changes to see if it would work; however, I am using it in this as an example to explain what I am looking for.

Comment: I know.  I pulled this jquery code out of another example that only used 1 check-all.  I just don't know how to manipulate it to work with all of my tables.  I am using classes in my tables for that very reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixing the ID issue, try:

```
$('.chkSelectAll').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('table').find('input[type="checkbox"]:gt(0)').prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'))
});
$('.permissions').find('input[type="checkbox"]:gt(0)').change(function () {
    var totalSibs = $(this).closest('table').find('input[type="checkbox"]:gt(0)').length;
    var checkedSibs = $(this).closest('table').find('input[type="checkbox"]:gt(0):checked').length;
    if (checkedSibs === 0) {
        $(this).closest('table').find('input[type="checkbox"]:first').prop('checked', false);
        $(this).closest('table').find('input[type="checkbox"]:first').prop('indeterminate', false);
    } else if (checkedSibs === totalSibs) {
        $(this).closest('table').find('input[type="checkbox"]:first').prop('checked', true);
        $(this).closest('table').find('input[type="checkbox"]:first').prop('indeterminate', false);
    } else {
        $(this).closest('table').find('input[type="checkbox"]:first').prop('indeterminate', true)
    }
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/sfu7h8wf/2/)**

Comment: That works perfect; however, I'm noticing that the check-all checkbox doesn't uncheck when one of the checkboxes are unchecked below it.  Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Here's an ever more powerful one and I think it's what you're looking for in your comment: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/sfu7h8wf/2/

Comment: That is awesome!  Works exactly the way I want it to.  I will accept your answer as soon as it lets me.